# How to override onSuggestionMouseEnter for Twitter typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead

I'm using Twitter Typeahead and have some problems when hovering the suggestions which triggers the hovered suggestion to pop up into my input field. If the user then presses enter the actual hovered value will be chosen and not what the user wrote. I would like it to be selected only if the user clicks the actual suggestion.
It seems to be the

```
_onSuggestionMouseEnter()
```

function that is fired when the mouse hovers a suggestion. My question is if it is possible to override this function in my own code? Or to solve this in another way?

This is my typeahead code:

```
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 100,
    remote: {
        url: 'url/to/suggestions',
        filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list.suggestions, function(word) {
                return {s: word.title};
            });
        }
    }
});

suggestions.initialize();
$('.typeahead').typeahead({highlight: true}, {
    source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
    name: 'suggestions',
    displayKey: 's',
    hint: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I solved it by adding a check on enter keypress like this:

```
$("#search-input").keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && hoverSuggestion) {
    $('.typeahead').typeahead('val', $('.twitter-typeahead pre').text());
    $('#search-input').text($('.twitter-typeahead pre').text())
    $('#search-form').submit();
  }
});
```

The hoveSuggestion variable is used to check if the arrows has been used and if so not go through with the cleaning of the suggestions. It is changed like this:

```
hoverSuggestion = true;
$('.typeahead').typeahead({highlight: true}, {
    source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
    name: 'suggestions',
    displayKey: 's',
    hint: true
}).on('typeahead:cursorchanged', function(event) {
    hoverSuggestion = false;
});
```

Not the most elegant solution but it works for now. Feedback are most welcome!